# slider.js sharepoint 2010 configuration

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, javascript

I am using slider.js (followed this : http://summit7systems.com/a-simple-jquery-content-slider-for-sharepoint-200720102013-and-o365/).

It all works fine, but if I wanted the slides to go from 0 1 2 3 4 3 2 1 0 and not 0 1 2 3 4 0 - how would this be done in javascript ?

Can anyone help with this. It scrolls back to 0 from the last tile.

```
            <script type="text/javascript"> 
        var slider = $('.hillbillyBanner').unslider(); // Move to the first slide 
        slider.unslider('animate:first'); 
        // Move to the third slide 
        // Remember, slides are zero-indexed so 0 is first slide, 1 is second, etc. 
    slider.unslider('animate:2'); 
        // Move to the last slide 
        slider.unslider('animate:last'); 
        // Move to the last slide and add a direction
 slider.unslider('animate:last,prev'); }); 
        </script>
```

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">      
var slider = $('.hillbillyBanner').unslider();

//  Move to the first slide
slider.unslider('animate:first');

//  Move to the third slide
//  Remember, slides are zero-indexed so 0 is first slide, 1 is second, etc.
slider.unslider('animate:2');

//  Move to the last slide
slider.unslider('animate:last');

//  Move to the last slide and add a direction
slider.unslider('animate:last,prev');
});
</script>

Comment: anyone got any advice on this ?